# Getting itemid from list<string>

Tags: android, gridview, baseadapter

i'm working on wallpaper app
i implemented this code in order to load my pictures from assets
[loading-images-from-assets-folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373251/gallery-shows-blank-when-loading-images-from-assets-folder)

it's working great but i have issue with getting itemid from the list to use the id to display one of these images in fullscreenactivity or setting wallpaper

```
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position ;
}
```

here is my code

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
 private Context mContext;
private List<String> list;
private AssetManager assetManager;

public ImageAdapter(Context c, List<String> list) {
    mContext = c;
   this.list = list;

}

public int getCount() {

    return list.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {

    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

    try {

        InputStream is = mContext.getAssets().open(list.get(position));
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(80, 80));
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return imageView;
}



public class Gs3Wallpaper extends Activity {
private  ImageButton Gs3Button;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.GridView1);
    try {
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this ,getImage()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    public List<String> getImage()throws IOException {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    String[] files = assetManager.list("gallary");
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String it : files) {
        list.add("gallary"+File.separator + it);        

    }
    return list;
```

i don't know how to get the id from the list i tried to use list.get(position) but it returns string not int so i can't pass that to setImageResource for example

any suggestions?

Comment: One suggestion, tell us what the problem is of getting the id that you are having

Comment: i don't know how to get the id from the list i tried to use list.get(position) but it returns string not int

Comment: Did you try using `onListeItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)` then `v.getId()`?

Comment: i tried alot of solutions but none worked i still can't get certain image via Id or position can anyone suggest something please?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is set the image or a path to the image, depending on how you are doing it, in a `HashMap` in `getView()` when you set the list item. Use the `position` for the `key` and the image as the `value`

```
public class MyClass
{
    HashMap<String, Bitmap> imageMap = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();
...
```

then set it in your `getView()`

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

try {

    InputStream is = mContext.getAssets().open(list.get(position));
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(80, 80));

    String posString = String.valueOf(position);
    imageMap.put(posString, bm);
} catch (IOException e) {
....
}
```

Something like this should work for you. Then just use the position to get that bitmap out of the `HashMap`